# Postfix continue sending mails with the hostname instead of the domain

Tags: server, 18.04, email, postfix, mail

I'm trying to configure Postfix to only send (not receive) emails. I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-debian-9) guide, but I didn't change my `hostname` to match my domain, because if I can avoid it, I would like to do it.

So, after trying a lot, I keep receiving emails with the `hostname` after the `@`, and it's quite frustrating, because I have replaced all the `$myhostname` variable occurrences in the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file with the domain name, but it's as if Postfix doesn't like it and continues sending emails with the `hostname` attached as domain. Here's my `main.cf` file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = example.com ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = example.com
mydestination = example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to tweak any other thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending mail? In particular, if you are using the `sendmail` command, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: By the way, it is also wrong for you to  set `myhostname` to `example.com` if your hostname isn't actually `example.com`. That is, if I don't reach your machine when I type `ping example.com`.

Comment: No, I'm sending the email with this command: `echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" personalemail@hotmail.com`

Comment: @fkraiem It's an example, in my `main.cf` I have my authentic registered domain.

Comment: The proper place to set your hostname is really `/etc/hostname` (and also `/etc/mailname`). And if you want to send mail with a different envelope address you can use for example `mailx` with the `-r` flag.

Comment: @fkraiem Exactly, it was that... I wasn't specifying the envelope address, so mail was taking it from the account I was using. I checked the received email deeper and it's correct. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @amedina please share with others your solution on a separate reply, be fair with the community

Answer (score 3):

The program `mail` from the package **mailutils** is adding the domain which then calls `sendmail` from the package **postfix**. By default, `mail` adds the shell variable *HOSTNAME* as the sender domain before calling `sendmail`. Either change *HOSTNAME* or edit **/etc/mailutils.conf** and add `program mail { address { email-domain sender.domain.my ; } }`.

Both `sendmail` and `mail` can be used to send an email. `sendmail` will add the domain listed in **/etc/*mail*name** if the sender does not already have a domain. As described above, `mail` will add the sender domain, overriding the `sendmail` configuration.

Note that *HOSTNAME* is set by **/etc/*host*name** while `sendmail` uses **/etc/*mail*name**.

To aid debugging, run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Also note, to finish an email in `sendmail` enter a line containing single period while to end an email in `mail` enter the EOF character `\<ctrl\>D`.

See also [Changing default domain in mailutils](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215388/changing-default-domain-in-mailutils)

Comment: So how does this answer the question?

Comment: I am trying to differentiate between the postfix settings and the mailutils settings. The question doesn't specify what program is used to send the email but a later comment shows that send is being used. I have attempted to highlight the difference between sendmail and mail, and the way each program determines the email domain, which is the issue raised in the question. I'm sorry if I am in error.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your answer to give first the answer and afterwards, the justification.  As your answer is written, it is difficult to follow. Something like: 'It depends on the software you use to send mail. For this software do that.  Justification:...

Comment: Thanks @Marc Vanhoomissen your feedback appreciated.

Comment: +1 - (Personally, I think it answered the question.) And they *do* mention they are using `mail` in the OP. This would explain why they see email sending as "user@hostname" / no fqdn.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/mailname` to have a single line, with your domain, and ending with a newline, e.g.:

```
example.com
```

Then edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to uncomment the line

```
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

rendering it as

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer is in /etc/hosts. There are 2 lines:

```
127.0.1.1       hostname.domain_name  hostname
192.168.0.47    hostname.domain_name  hostname
```

Delete the "hostname", and the lines become:

```
127.0.1.1      domain_name  hostname
192.168.0.47   domain_name  hostname
```

It works!